# LDAPAuthenticator for AD on JupyterHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, ldap, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

I'm attempting to use the `LDAPAuthenticator` class found [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/ldapauthenticator) to configure JupyterHub on EMR.

I'm querying ActiveDirectory through LDAP to get the authorized users, which are members of a specific AD group.

Problem I'm running into is that with this specific [implementation](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html), it expects the user objects to have a few specific user attributes that the objects don't have as of now and I'm not allowed to change them.

The ideal workflow would be, `LDAPSEARCH` queries `ActiveDirectory` for a specific AD group, and on return it creates users for the members of that AD group, it should create linux users and directories for the users.

I'd like to know if anyone else has run into this sort of issue and overcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get stuck in the same place, I ended up using this:

https://github.com/hansohn/jupyterhub-ldap-authenticator

and it work as expected.